# Selectable components in Visual Studio 2013 Setup Project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wix, windows-installer, installshield, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have created a Visual Studio 2013 Setup Project that installs a Windows Service. Everything works fine up to now, but I need to add an additional component to the installation. This component should install if the user wishes, so, I need something like a selectable component that the user can check its installation if it is desired. I searched the web but not happy results, I don't know if it is possible to do with the Basic Visual Studio Setup Projects Template. I need to know if it is possible, or if I need to move to other Installer's maker like Wix or Installshield. If it is possible, please explain how to achieve it. Thanks

Comment: If the installer extension is anything like those projects used to be, then you add a UI dialog box such as Checkboxes from the canned list of dialogs, a checked state causes an uppercase property name to be set (CHECKBOXESA maybe) then you condition the file you're adding on that value, perhaps CHECKBOXESA=1. This always was horrible because thee correct way to do this is with features, actual Windows Installer features that you can add at install time or later add/delete from Programs&Features. You may be better off in the long run moving to another tool.

Comment: @PhilDW- thanks, I figure it out to do exactly what you are saying, but there are problems, for example, if a users does not check anything how do I stop the installer for continuing to the next page? There are other minus problems I can deal with, but this one I haven't figure it out.

Comment: VS setups aren't the best for doing this kind of thing. Would RadioButtons work? That's a dialog too, and there's always one activated.

Comment: But, the problem with RadioButtons is that no more than one can be activated at the same time.

Comment: If there isn't a dialog that works for you then you've answered your own question about changing to some other tool to build your MSI file. VS is for basic installs with limited UI and no code running in the UI, and those other tools will have a bigger learning curve because they expose all the features of Windows Installer to you, and VS setup projects don't.

Comment: thanks @PhilDW I will take into account change the tool. !